File drop automation not working (not getting triggered)
I'm trying to transfer .txt file with ; as a delimiter from SFTP server to a Data Extension in SFMC, but my file drop automation is not being triggered when this happens. The process should look like this: firstly, a file is transferred from another SFTP server (few times a day) to the one from which I'm suppose to import the data from, and then an automation should get that data and overwrite the target DE every time a new file appears in the folder, which sounds simple, since I can import the data successfully but only and only if I drop the file manually on the server. I've done this a few times before and it has worked, the only difference is that the previous times is was Azure->FTP relation, not FTP->FTP. I can't think of anything else relevant to include here, since the configuration of the automation and the Import file seem to work just fine if the file is being manually dropped. What else could be causing this? Thanks.

Are you sure that you have a consistent file naming pattern in all places? Even a small typo might prevent the automation from catching your file and getting triggered.

@Niko I've been careful with that, firstly I had set the automation with a file naming pattern, and it worked as well, but same as mentioned in the post, only if the file was manually dropped.. Then I changed it to no file naming pattern just to be safe because it was not being triggered those few times a day, but the situation is still the same.. The File Naming Pattern in the Import file is %%BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%.txt . I only have one activity in the automation.
